# Set table size problem

Tags: tables, size

I'm writing a paper now and I have the format problem as shown in the following snip
[image]

I follow the latex code for the table

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   Brand & community & Neutral\_Average & Negative\_Average & Positive\_Average  \\ \hline
   Apple & NEWS & 1.45 & 2.93 & 2.72 \\ \hline
   Apple & Amazon & 0.069 & 0.39 & 0.71 \\ \hline
   Apple & Twitter & 17.11 & 11.36 & 12.06 \\ \hline
 Huawei & Amazon&0.076 & 0.20 & 1 \\ \hline
 Huawei & Twitter& 13.56 & 5.3 & 10.58 \\ \hline
 Huawei & NEWS&1.034 & 1.73 & 1.75 \\ \hline
  Samsung & NEWS & 1.03 & 1.83 & 3.37 \\ \hline
  Samsung & Twitter & 10.82 & 4.52 & 11.62 \\ \hline
  Samsung & Amazon & 0.093& 0.35& 1.1 \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
\caption{Average Brand Sentiment Per Community}
\label{brand_senti_community}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please do tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart} - This is the type of class that proposed by the conference

Comment: Instead, please update  you example to include document class and a small preamble (enough for it to be compilable). Use can use the `kantlipsum` package and its `\kant` macro to generate sample text, so we do not need the bibliography. The point is to provide code for those who want to help, in such a way that the code provided can be used as is.

Comment: Hopefully, you are using `twocolumn` option in your template, if yes, please use  `table*` instead of `table`, if this not suits, then provide the `MWE` (from `documentclass{...}...\end{document}`

Comment: I did the edition of the code, regarding the bibliography it's just for showing how the table affected by the layout

Comment: Sorry but I can't change the document class because it's part of conference structure

Comment: @Peter - Your code does not create a two-column layout. Is something missing?

Comment: @Mico I attach only the code of the table. So do you mean that there should be a specific code for a table that fit the two columns layout ?!

Comment: @Peter - It would really help if your code provided sufficient detail to let others (more or less) reproduce the issue you wish to fix. If you don't provide the required detail information, others will have to make some guesses as to what's really going on. Their guesses may be valid, in which case everyone is happy, or they may not be valid, leading to answers which will probably not usable by you. There is more than one way to create a two-column layout: Why force others into pointless guesswork? It's up to you to decide how important it is to you to receive usable and useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't indicate how your document sets up two-column mode, so I had to make some assumptions, which may or may not be appropriate for *your* document.

The `tabular` environment currently exceeds the width of the column because there is unbreakable and long text in three header cells. I suggest that your reorganize the header to give it more structure and to make each individual cell less wide. In the example below, I also employ a `tabular*` environment and set its overall width to `\columnwidth`.

I would further like to suggest that you give the table a  more open "look" by omitting all vertical rules and by using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules. To enhance legibility, I would also align the numbers in the three numeric columns on their respective decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf,twocolumn]{acmart} 
\usepackage{lipsum}   % for filler text
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
%\centering % not needed 

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
        l l 
        S[table-format=2.3] 
   *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
\toprule
   Brand & Community & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Average Brand Sentiment}\\
\cmidrule{3-5}
& & {Neutral} & {Negative} & {Positive}  \\
\midrule
   Apple & NEWS    & 1.45 & 2.93 & 2.72 \\
   Apple & Amazon  & 0.069 & 0.39 & 0.71 \\
   Apple & Twitter & 17.11 & 11.36 & 12.06 \\
\addlinespace
  Huawei & Amazon  &0.076 & 0.20 & 1 \\
  Huawei & Twitter & 13.56 & 5.3 & 10.58 \\
  Huawei & NEWS    &1.034 & 1.73 & 1.75 \\ 
\addlinespace
  Samsung & NEWS   & 1.03 & 1.83 & 3.37 \\
  Samsung & Twitter& 10.82 & 4.52 & 11.62 \\ 
  Samsung & Amazon & 0.093& 0.35& 1.1 \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Average Sentiment, by Brand and Community}
\label{brand_senti_community}
\end{table}

\lipsum % some filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico This answer works well for me with one error message in S[table-format=2.3] 
   *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]} } which is (illegal charecter in array arg)

Comment: @Peter: Did you load the `siunitx` package?

Comment: @leandriis Yes I already load the package but I meet another problem. because I use the same code of above with another table contains countries names instead of numbers so there is a problem in it because maybe siunitx is only for number

Comment: @Peter - The purpose of the `S` column type is definitely to align numbers on their decimal markers. Non-numeric data in cells in a column of type `S` must be encased in curly braces -- exactly as is already done with `{Neutral}`, `{Negative}`, and `{Positive}` in the code shown above. If a column contains (mostly) country names, you shouldn't be using the `S` column type for that column.

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot, it works with me